# Visual Studio: "str() is not a member of std::ostringstream"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, std, ostringstream

I have a compiler error with Visual Studio 2013 (while Xcode 6.2 compiles) which I can't make any sense of:

following example code is an abstract, reduced excerpt from a format conversion:

```
#include<sstream>
void main(...){
    (std::ostringstream()<<0).str();
}
```

while following version compiles:

```
#include<sstream>
void main(...){
    (std::ostringstream()).str();
}
```

context:

```
std::string result=(std::ostringstream()<<value).str();
```

what do I miss here?
Thanks!

Comment: thanks, for the suggestion, yes, the post was unclear on that, but, yes, <string> has been included before <sstream>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is `error C2039: 'str': is not a member of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'`. It's complaining that `str` is missing in `std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>` aka `std::ostream`, not `std::ostringstream`.

`std::ostringstream`'s `operator<<` still returns `std::ostream&` (it inherits these operators from `std::ostream`), which has no `str()` member.

Clang/libc++ (which is what Xcode uses) implements an extension in its rvalue stream insertion operator that

1. Makes it a better match for rvalue streams compared to the inherited member `operator<<`s, and
2. returns a reference to the stream as is, without conversion to `std::ostream&`.

Together this made your code compile in Xcode.

To call `.str()`, you can manually `static_cast` `(std::ostringstream()<<value)` back to `std::ostringstream&` (use either `std::ostringstream &&` or `const std::ostringstream&` for libc++ compatibility, since its rvalue stream insertion operator returns an rvalue reference to the stream).

Comment: thanks everybody, thats working! What a fast solution!
It was all my fault wrongly reading the error message: it must read "str() is not a member of std::ostream" 
Thanks for pointing that out and providing the cast solution!

Comment: to compile with clang as well, a const is needed:
static_cast<const std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream()<<value).str()

Answer (score 0):

From my compiler, it actually says `sst.cpp(3) : error C2039: “str”: is not a member of “std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_trait
s<char>>”`. Note that it is about **ostream** instead of **ostringstream**. The `<<` is an operator defined for `ostream` (`std::ostream::operator<<`, you can refer to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)).

So you can actually cast `ostream` back to `ostringstream` using `static_cast<>`, since the returned object is actually of a latter class, like the following code:

```
#include<sstream>
void main(...){
    (static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << 0)).str();
}
```

will compile.

Comment: No, it won't compile.

Comment: Heh, VS2013 is even more broken than I thought. The cast should be to `std::ostringstream &`. It doesn't actually work properly AFAICT, though (check what `str()` returns).

Comment: @T.C. Using `std::ostream const&` should work without a hitch.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Huh? I don't think so.

Comment: Yeah that's a real problem, updated my code. Thanks for corrections.

Comment: Thanks as well! You are correct! The casting solution works!
I am sorry I can't upvote yet (newbie)

Comment: @T.C. Why not? The temporary is definitely alive until the end of the expression. In fact, the non-`const` version works, too; I initially thought it shouldn’t work because it’s attempting to bind a temporary to a non-`const` reference, which is forbidden. However, no binding is taking place here. The only problem with this code is that `void main()` is an illegal signature in C++.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Wait, did you mean `ostream` or `ostringstream`?

Comment: @T.C. Argh. The latter.